# Lost database for cakephp project

Tags: cakephp

I´ve lost the database for a cakephp project.

My questions are:

As Ruby on Rails, which allows to create a seed DB with the app code…

Can I do the same with cakephp, and, even although i lost the data, I can run the app from scratch?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: CakePHP has support for doing this, but we have no way to know whether the person that wrote your application took advantage of it.

Comment: Many thanks, @GregSchmidt. But then...how to solve this?  Some info where i can comb the hank out?

Comment: Well, for starters, what version of CakePHP are you using? [Here](https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/seeding.html) is the current manual for database seeds, but it may not apply to your version.